# Array sort with primary and secondary value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

Is there a way to sort an array of objects using a primary and secondary value? What i mean is an array like this:

```
[
    { primary: 0, secondary: 'a' },
    { primary: 1, secondary: 'a' },
    { primary: 1, secondary: 'b' },
    { primary: 0, secondary: 'b' }
]
```

will be sorted using the primary value, so the first two objects with the primary value of 0 come first then the values of 1 come second, and then it will be again sorted by the secondary value and it will result in the array becoming

```
[
    { primary: 0, secondary: 'a' },
    { primary: 0, secondary: 'b' },
    { primary: 1, secondary: 'a' },
    { primary: 1, secondary: 'b' }
]
```

im havent really touched the `Array.sort()` before so im trying to find out how to do this, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comparison would be by `primary` first (numeric), or by `secondary` if equal (string using [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare))

```js
const arr = [ { primary: 0, secondary: 'a' }, { primary: 1, secondary: 'a' }, { primary: 1, secondary: 'b' }, { primary: 0, secondary: 'b' } ];

const res = arr.sort((a, b) => 
  a.primary - b.primary || a.secondary.localeCompare(b.secondary)
);

console.log(res);
```